# Shorthand for applying an entire object to another object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Is there a shorthand for this:

```
canvas.width = size.width;
canvas.height = size.height;
```

There are no other keys in the `size` object.

Comment: You want to (essentially) clone an object?

Comment: I guess more like _merge_ instead of clone, @VLAZ

Comment: @JordiNebot yeah, I know there is a difference but I am not sure which is OP after.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to mutate the target object you can use `Object.assign`.

```
Object.assign(canvas, size);
```

Alternatively if you wish to merge into a new object you can provide an empty target.

```
var result = Object.assign({}, canvas, size);
```

Or use the ES6 spread operator, but it's just syntax sugar for the above.

```
var result = { ...canvas, ...size };
```

Comment: The last one was what I was looking for, but it doesn't work, size replaces canvas, it might be because canvas is an html object. (document.getElementById)

Comment: If you just want to merge the contents of `size` into your existing `canvas` I would recommend trying the first example. Using either of the two non-mutating examples won't copy the `prototype` to the target object, if `canvas` is an `HTMLElement` you probably want the `prototype` to be preserved.

Answer (score 3):

You can just merge two objects, provided `canvas` is defined and is an object:

```
canvas = {...canvas, ...size}
```

Comment: FYI, this is for the newer version of js (from ES6)

Comment: This is what I looked for, however, it doesn't work, size replaces canvas, it might be because `canvas` is an html object. (document.getElementById)

Comment: See @UncleDave's first use of `Object.assign`, cause the spread operator will create a new object.

Answer (score 0):

For an older browser that does not support the other methods you could use:

```js
function moveFields(from, to) {
    Object.keys(from).forEach(function(key) { to[key] = from[key] });
}
```

Works even in IE9

Answer (score 0):

At the bare minimum, you can write your assignment as -

```
`const canvas = { ...size };`
```

A test sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/57803690-9h0fu).